# Mapbox map is not filling the entire div, even with map.resize() call

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

My website has Mapbox maps for golf course locations.

Here's an example page, scroll down to see the map:
https://www.golfscout.net/golf-course/harborside-international-golf-center-port-course-chicago-illinois

Problem: On Chrome desktop, the map often (not always) only shows for half the space of the div, making it look cut off. Here's a screenshot of what that looks like:
https://www.golfscout.net/images/mapbox-half-map.jpg

This is using Mapbox GL JS v2.13.0.

I thought map reload call would fix it, but it doesn't:

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.resize();
});
```

It generally seems to work okay on Safari and Firefox. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's the full map code:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<token>';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
    center: [-87.588567551718, 41.694580079560],
    zoom: 10
});

const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([-87.588567551718, 41.694580079560])
    .addTo(map);

map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

map.on('load', function () {
    map.resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I load your page, the map loads with that height initially then the container dynamically increases in height after the images around it load.

The best option is to set the map at the correct height from the start, just set a height that matches the image displayed next to it, or put the map on its own row.

If you really want to use `map.resize()` You'll need to fire it after the image loads, something like

```js
let img = document.querySelector('#id-of-image-next-to-map');

img.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  map.resize()
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error.  "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')". I've added the code to the page linked from the original post, if you want to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, I went through the same situation in an ionic project with Angular. The solution was to initialize the map inside an ionViewDidEnter() code block:

```
ionViewDidEnter(): void { 
    this.initializeMap();
}

initializeMap(): void {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'YOUR_MAP_CONTAINER',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-0, 0],
      zoom: 10
    });
}
```